# EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer in spring boot 2.0

Tags: java, spring-boot

I try to migrate my app from spring boot 1.5 to 2.0
The problem is that I cannot find EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer.
Any ideas how to make it through?

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer customizer() {
    return container -> container.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, "/unauthenticated"));
}
```

**Update:**
I found it as ServletWebServerFactoryCustomizer in  org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet package.

```
@Bean
public ServletWebServerFactoryCustomizer customizer() {
    return container -> container.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, "/unauthenticated"));
}
```

But there is an error:
Cannot resolve method

> 'addErrorPages(org.springframework.boot.web.server.ErrorPage)'

I also had to change import of new Error Page from `org.springframework.boot.web.servlet` to `org.springframework.boot.web.server`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you need `ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory`, instead of `ServletWebServerFactoryCustomizer`.

You can find the code snippet below:

```
import org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.undertow.UndertowServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.web.server.ErrorPage;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;

@Configuration
public class ServerConfig {

    @Bean
    public ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory webServerFactory() {
        UndertowServletWebServerFactory factory = new UndertowServletWebServerFactory();
        factory.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, "/unauthenticated"));
        return factory;
    }
}
```

The above code is for Undertow. For tomcat, you need to replace `UndertowServletWebServerFactory` with `TomcatServletWebServerFactory`.

You will need to add the following dependency to your project (in case of Maven):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.undertow</groupId>
    <artifactId>undertow-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.26.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 6):

You don't need the container customizer to register your error pages. Simple bean definition implemented as a lambda does the trick:

```
@Bean
public ErrorPageRegistrar errorPageRegistrar() {
    return registry -> {
        registry.addErrorPages(
            new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, "/unauthenticated"),
        );
    };
}
```

Comment: The question is which approach is better or where should we use the WebServerFactoryCustomizer instead?

Answer (score 2):

From Spring Boot 2 on the *WebServerFactoryCustomizer* has replaced the *EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer*:

```
@Bean
public WebServerFactoryCustomizer<ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory> webServerFactoryCustomizer() {
    return (factory) -> factory.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, "/401.html"));
}
```

**Alternatively** you might add a view controller like

```
@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/unauthorized").setViewName("forward:/401.html");
}
```

and then your WebServerFactory should point to /unauthorized instead:

```
@Bean
public WebServerFactoryCustomizer<ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory> webServerFactoryCustomizer() {
    return (factory) -> factory.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, "/unauthorized"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the code snippet below:

```
@Bean
public ErrorPageRegistrar errorPageRegistrar(){
    return new MyErrorPageRegistrar();
}

// ...

private static class MyErrorPageRegistrar implements ErrorPageRegistrar {

    @Override
    public void registerErrorPages(ErrorPageRegistry registry) {
        registry.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "/400"));
    }

}
```