# EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer(spring 2 and spring boot 2) changed to WebServerFactoryCustomizer (spring 5 and spring boot 2)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, embeddedwebserver

Whether the below changes will work fine in spring 5 ?

Please suggest the right way to proceed

Spring 2:

```
  @Bean
  public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer()
  {
    return container -> 
    {
      container.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "/not-found"));
    };
  }
```

spring 5 :

```
@Bean
  public WebServerFactoryCustomizer containerCustomizer()
  {
    return container -> 
    {
      TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
    factory.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "/not-found"));
      container = factory;
    };

  }
```

I referenced the below links,

[EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer in spring boot 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49406779/embeddedservletcontainercustomizer-in-spring-boot-2-0?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent code in Spring Boot 2 is the following:

```
@Bean
public WebServerFactoryCustomizer<ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory> webServerFactoryCustomizer() {
    return (factory) -> factory.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "/not-found"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your brilliant reply but one thing that I don't get is what is wrong with directly mapping to the error page that we already have?
    @Bean
    public WebServerFactoryCustomizer<ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory> webServerFactoryCustomizer() {
        return (factory) -> factory.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "/404.html"));
    }

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that. My example above is specific to the question where `/not-found` was being used.

Comment: Does anyone know if the Spring Boot 2.x approach work for non-embedded Tomcat?  I'm working on an app with 2 WARs in a single TC instance.  All of the Spring Boot 1.5.x customization interfaces work only with an embedded Tomcat.

Comment: Spring Boot 2.x's customization also only applies to embedded Tomcat. If you're deploying a war file to an external Tomcat, you should configure it using server.xml and context.xml.